# Как в метод контроллера передать один из дочерних классов?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Чтобы не приводить огромное количество кода, я приведу пример, который можно будет масштабировать на мой проект.

У меня есть родительский класс `BaseRequest`, у которого есть 2 наследника: `FirstRequest` и `SecondRequest`.

Также у меня есть метод у контроллера, который принимает значения из формы:

```
public JsonResponse<BaseRequest> ChangeCustomerInfo(BaseRequest request)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return "";
   }
   ...
}
```

Есть ли какая-то возможность реализовать корректно работу данного метода, чтобы он мог принимать как `FirstRequest`, так и `SecondRequest`?

Comment: @Bulson он не будет совершать приведение и считает, что ему пришел именно родительский класс

Comment: [Polymorphic model binding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#polymorphic-model-binding)